# How to send push notification to client app from merchant app in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notification to the client app from the merchant app with button click. Both are two different android apps. How can I achieve does anybody have solution for this?

Comment: please refer this https://blog.usejournal.com/send-device-to-device-push-notifications-without-server-side-code-238611c143

Comment: Thank you for the help but i still couldn't get how can i do it for two different apps,implementing singelton code in costumer app can solve the issue?